# Упростить вид множества

Tags: множества, дискретная-математика

Упростить вид множества, заданной с помощью
операций, применяя законы алгебры множеств (в ответ множества
могут входить не более одного раза):
(A ∩ ¯B)∆(¯A ∩ B)
А как дальше?
Могу ли я взять ¯B и[image: введите сюда описание изображения] перенести в лево B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, тут удобно пользоваться рисунками. Рисуешь два пересекающихся круга: множество A и множество B (рисунки есть, например, [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)). Далее используешь разную закраску для двух множеств: (A ∩ ¯B) и (¯A ∩ B). Все, что закращено 1м и 2м цветом, но не обоими, есть ответ. Думаю, там просто будет понять, что ответ -- это A∆B.

Если же идти формальным путем, то

```
(A ∩ ¯B)∆(¯A ∩ B) = ((A ∩ ¯B) ⋃ (¯A ∩ B)) \ ((A ∩ ¯B) ⋂ (¯A ∩ B)) = A∆B \ ∅ = A∆B, т.к.:
(A ∩ ¯B) ⋃ (¯A ∩ B) = {x: (x∈A & x∉B) ∨ (x∉A & x∈B)} = A∆B
(A ∩ ¯B) ⋂ (¯A ∩ B) = {x: (x∈A & x∉B) & (x∉A & x∈B)} = ∅
```